# Add new row in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add new row to a gridview. The value of each cell comes from the bottom blank cells.
How to grab the cell's value?

```
private void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["test"];
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        // not sure how to add
    }
```

[image]
Please also notice there is a checkbox in a column.

Thanks.

Comment: add the newrow to the datatable, then update the gridview, 

ds.Tables["Test"].rows.add(dr);
could be addrow instead of add just wrote this from memory

Comment: The user needs add values at runtime, the values are from these cells. The user only can access the interface rather than code.

Comment: ...i know, but in your code you comment saying you arent sure how to add the new row, i just explained it

Comment: Okay. I don't how to get the cell's name such as cell1.ToString() something like.

Comment: cells are ordered accroding to a 0 based index. the first cell along a row is cell 0, the second cell is cell 1, etc

Comment: Is the last row's cell: grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count].Cells[1] something like?

Comment: soemthing like that should get you the second cell in the last row

Comment: Where are you trying to add the new row? Because the DataGridView handles the addition of the row to itself!

Comment: `grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]` because it's 0 based index meaning it starts counting at 0.

Comment: DataGridView handles the addition, how? Can you please...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be used

```
//define datatable (with all columns you want to have)...
  DataRow dr;
  int lastRow = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count-2;
  for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
     // grab the values from the last row cells.
     dr[i] = dataGridView1[i, lastRow].Value;
   }
     dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Self reslove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
DataColumn values = new DataColumn("Test");
myTable.Columns.Add(values);
DataRow rd = myTable.NewRow();
rd["Test"] ="";
myTable.Rows.Add(rd);
datagridview1.DataSource = myTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add Rows to the datatable by using the Add method.

```
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

You can access the values by using the overloaded brackets.

```
dt.Rows[a][b]
```

will give you the value at a certain row and certain column

To get the value of the Checkbox you can cast the object retrieved from dt.Rows[a][b] to a checkbox and then get the value of the Checked attribute.

```
((CheckBox)dt.Rows[a][b]).Checked
```

Hope this helps,

Matt